# Show Loading Screen on Home Screen Widget Android

Tags: android-widget

I understand the "android:initialLayout" element within the xml folder for defining the default layout of an Android homescreen widget.  I want to be able to display a "loading your information" on my widget while I am waiting for data...how do I do this. I have tried to display an error message on my widget if there is no connectivity, but it doesn't get past the "android:initialLayout" , so showing code I believe is irrelevant.  Correct me if I am wrong please...don't bash me.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the initialLayout is so that your widget displays something before Android has had a chance to call your widget-updating code. This is a great place to put a "Loading..." message.

Once your onUpdate method is called in your widget, that is your chance to get your data. If you have a connectivity problem at that point, you can display an error message at that point. Otherwise, if you successfully get your data, then you can draw you widget with the data.

I'm not sure if I've answered your question, so apologies if I have not. Please clarify a bit more if I have not. The main questions I have are:

1. Is Android calling your onUpdate function? Log statements can be really helpful for this.
2. Are you trying to load your data in the background, such as a separate Service, and then reading the results in the widget? Or are you loading the data inside the widget?